# command line interpreter in c

Tags: c, command-line, open-source

I want to create a console "shell" for an embedded device.
anyone knows about an open-source implementation of such a thing in c ?
I need basic line parsing to commands & arguments.

Something similar to uboot - console shell will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You may find usefull piece of codes in this [shell](https://github.com/ziirish/shelldone) a friend of mine is writting.
His aim is to learn issues regarding the shell coding, so this project should keep small and easily readable.

Comment: Thanks for your link, however it will not do, I'm programming an embedded device, so I don't have the privilege of OS abstractions such as stdio, stderr, etc. besides, most of the libraries also doesn't exist. that mean that I need to write everything from scratch. u-boot was an example to what I need, u-boot is loaded before linux, so you need to write your own implementation of everything...

Answer (score 0):

There is/was the book "Linux application development"
It implements a Shell as example. I found this quite convincing.